# Different between $('#id') vs $(id)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What difference between this two code? Because when i test it using chrome console it give return same value. Is this mean if not put '#' that mean it automatically assume it as for id?

Comment: you're using variable `id`, assume there have already assigned with a selector something like `var id = '#id';`

Comment: Read the jQuery documentation https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ It is the same thing as CSS selectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript source code, `foo` is a **variable**, `'foo'` is a **string literal** (representing the string *value* `foo`). Variables can hold string values:

```
var bar = 'xyz';
```

In this example the *variable* `bar` is assigned the *string* value `xyz`.

Therefore, `$('#id')` passes the string value `#id` to the `$` function. `$(id)` on the other hand passes the value *of* the variable `id` to the function.

These are very different operations but of course they can have the same outcome.

---

I think you'd benefit the most from reading a JavaScript tutorial such as http://eloquentjavascript.net/ .

Answer (score 1):

Look up jquery selectors at jquery.org.  # in the  string means the string is an id. ".classname" will use the class name to find it.  Selectors can be very complicated so it will be worth your time to look it up.